# Get a list of column names only

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-connector

I've been looking around the Internet for quite some time now, but I can't find a way to get a list of just column names. I don't care about the data each column has.

I want to take that list and compare it against a collection. I'm using the VB.NET MySqlConnector. I'm new to using the connector.

Edit:

```
Dim mscCMD As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SHOW COLUMNS FROM OCN.cpu", msc)
            Dim sqlReader As MySqlDataReader = mscCMD.ExecuteReader()
            Dim b As Integer = 0
            Dim c As Integer = 0
            While sqlReader.Read
                msProjects(c) = sqlReader.**Item**(b)
                b += 1
                c += 1
            End While
```

Never mind, I figured it out. I had to choose Item, not getName.

Edit: Perhaps I didn't just yet. It's reading one row. I'm unsure how to move to the next row. For example

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM City;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
**Id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment**
| Name       | char(35) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Country    | char(3)  | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| District   | char(20) | YES  | MUL |         |                |
| Population | int(11)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

That's the row it reads it reads. Once you go past the 5th item, you're out of bounds.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I'm only experienced with VB. All that I've accomplished so far, in SQL, has been by looking up tutorials.

Comment: So do you just need the correct SQL statement?

Comment: Yes, that would help. However, I will also need help with the connector too. The statement will product an output, so I need to know how to properly turn that output into a collection. Right now, I only know how to execute non queries.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html - Executing that will result in a result-set. execute it just like a normal query. There are also meta-table that can be queried.

Comment: Thanks for kicking me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the metadata from a result set:

```
         final ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `" + tableName +"` LIMIT 0,1;");
         final ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
         for(int i=1; i<metaData.getColumnCount(); i++)
         {
             System.out.println("" + metaData.getColumnName(i));
         }
```

Also, you can get the java.sql.Types column type the same way.

Comment: I'm not using Java. I'm using VB.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Found the answer from a MS KB article.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310108

```
For Each myField In schemaTable.Rows
    'For each property of the field...
     For Each myProperty In schemaTable.Columns
        'Display the field name and value.
         Console.WriteLine(myProperty.ColumnName & " = " & myField(myProperty).ToString())
     Next
     Console.WriteLine()

     'Pause.
     Console.ReadLine()
Next
```

Specifically `myField(myProperty).ToString`will get you the column names. It will also contain other things about the column. You will have to sort through it, but all the column names from your table will be in there.